# Grid_forget() doesn't seem to forget widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a problem regarding tkinter's grid_forget() method. I have 2 pages in a notebook and I want to show certain widgets on the second page based off the user's selected options in the first page, I have a multiple choice menu and the grid_forget() method seems to work well until I select 2 or more options from the menu. I tried creating the widgets when an option is selected and place them based on the choice, no luck there, also tried creating them with the rest of the widgets and when the user selected an option I would simply just use grid to place them on the screen, also no luck there. I created a demo below, sorry for potential mistakes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
SMALL_FONT = ("calibri", 16)
class App(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self, height = "900", width = "1600")
    self.notebook.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.frame_pasul3 = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
    self.frame_pasul1 = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
    self.notebook.add(self.frame_pasul1, text = "First page")
    self.notebook.add(self.frame_pasul3, text = "Second page")
    self.first_page()
def first_page(self):
    options = ["Urmarire mobiliara",
                "Urmarire imobiliara", 
                "Predarea silita bunuri imobile",
                "Predarea silita bunuri mobile",
                "Obligatia de a face",
                "Executare minori"] 
    
    menubutton_modalitate_exec = tk.Menubutton(self.frame_pasul1, text="Alegeti o modalitate de executare", 
                               indicatoron=True, borderwidth=1, fg = "#000000",relief="raised")
    menu_modalitate_exec = tk.Menu(menubutton_modalitate_exec, tearoff=False)
    menubutton_modalitate_exec.configure(menu=menu_modalitate_exec)
    menubutton_modalitate_exec.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    self.modalitate = {}

    for choice in options:
        self.modalitate[choice] = tk.StringVar()
        menu_modalitate_exec.add_checkbutton(label=choice, variable=self.modalitate[choice], 
                             onvalue=1, offvalue=0, 
                             command=self.printValues)
    self.second_page()

def second_page(self):
    self.frame3_titlu_exec = ttk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_titlu_exec.grid()
    self.frame3_text = ttk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_text.grid()
    self.frame3_creante = tk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_creante.grid()
    self.frame3_reprezentand_obligatia = tk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_judecatorie = ttk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_judecatorie.grid()
    self.frame3_texte = tk.Frame(self.frame_pasul3)
    self.frame3_texte.grid()
    ttk.Label(self.frame3_titlu_exec, font = SMALL_FONT, text = "Titlu Executoriu").grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4 ,pady = 10)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_titlu_exec, text = "Contract de credit.").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_titlu_exec, text = "Sentinta civila.").grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_titlu_exec, text = "Contract notarial.").grid(row = 1, column = 2,padx = 10, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_titlu_exec, text = "Act de adjudecare.").grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
    self.entry = tk.Text(self.frame3_text, height = 2, wrap = "word", font = ("Helvetica", 10))
    self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 15)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_text, text = "Incarca titlu").grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 15)
    ttk.Label(self.frame3_creante, font = SMALL_FONT, text = "Creante").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.btn_adauga_creante = ttk.Button(self.frame3_creante, text = "Adauga")
    self.btn_adauga_creante.grid(row = 0, column = 3)       

    self.reprezentand_fapt_label = ttk.Label(self.frame3_judecatorie, font = SMALL_FONT, text = "Ce reprezinta fapta.")
    self.reprezentand_fapt_label.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    self.reprezentand_creante = tk.Text(self.frame3_judecatorie, height = 3, width = 70)
    self.reprezentand_creante.grid(row = 3 , column = 1, pady = 15)
    ttk.Label(self.frame3_texte, font = SMALL_FONT, text = "Judecatorie").grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    options_jud = ["optiunea 2.",
                        "test 3",
                        "test 4",
                        "test 5"]
    self.judecatorie = ttk.Combobox(self.frame3_texte, values = options_jud)
    self.judecatorie.set("Selecteaza o judecatorie.")
    self.judecatorie.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_texte, text = "Pasul 2. Parti dosar.").grid(row  = 6, column = 0, padx = 15, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)
    ttk.Button(self.frame3_texte, text = "Pasul 4. Cheltuieli de executare").grid(row = 6, column = 3, ipadx = 15, ipady = 5)

def printValues(self):
    for name, var in self.modalitate.items():
        if var.get() == "1" and (name == "Predarea silita bunuri imobile" or name == "Predarea silita bunuri mobile" or name == "Obligatia de a face" or name == "Executare minori"):
            self.reprezentand_creante_label = tk.Label(self.frame3_judecatorie, font = SMALL_FONT, text = "Ce reprezinta creanta.")
            self.reprezentand_creante = tk.Text(self.frame3_judecatorie, wrap = "word", height = 3, width = 70)
            self.ok_modalitate_exec = 1
            self.reprezentand_creante_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 15)
            self.reprezentand_creante.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 15)
            print("Avem 1 la cele 4", name, var.get())
            break
        elif var.get() == "0" and (name == "Predarea silita bunuri imobile" or name == "Predarea silita bunuri mobile" or name == "Obligatia de a face" or name == "Executare minori"):
            print("Avem 0 la cele 4", name, var.get())
            self.ok_modalitate_exec = 0
            self.reprezentand_creante_label.grid_forget()
            self.reprezentand_creante.grid_forget()
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
main_window = tk.Tk()
app = App(main_window)
app.grid()
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have used same set of instance variables for the newly created label and text box when option "Predarea silita bunuri mobile" or "Obligatia de a face" or "Executare minori" is selected, so only the last set of label and text box are referenced.  When you deselect the above options, the last set of label and text box are `grid_forget()`, but the previous sets are not.  Since they are put in the same positions, so you may think `grid_forget()` does not work.

Comment: i see now, thank you for your answer. Basically I should create the label and text box in the second page function and in printValues just grid them/grid_forget()

Comment: or maybe i should keep a reference to every label and text box created in the function and find a way to grid_forget() those instances?